# ¿Es correcto abreviar "visto bueno " como "VoBo."?

Tags: abreviaturas

Muchas veces he visto que lo abrevian como *VoBo.* por ejemplo dentro de la compañía donde trabajo. Sin embargo, no sé si realmente es correcto.

Lo que me parece extraño de la abreviación es que las dos palabras están juntas y cada una de ellas con su letra inicial en mayúscula. ¿Es acaso esto una regla para juntar dos o más palabras en una sola abreviación?

Comment: Aunque parezca raro V° B° está correcto, en cambio, VoBo (y que casualmente al leerlo suena "Bobo"), jamás en mi vida la había visto abreviado así.

Comment: @Pedro La tecla que tiene º y ª por alguna razón es muy poco usada, por ejemplo suelen poner los ordinales como "3o" o "2a"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

El [apéndice de abreviaturas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/apendices/apendice2.html) del Panhispánico de Dudas de la RAE lo recoge como:

> V.º B.º

Esto sigue las normas generales de [formación](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=fKODyKTfZD6s0mX7bz#3) y [ortografía](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=fKODyKTfZD6s0mX7bz#6) de las de abrevaciones:

> Entre las abreviaturas formadas por contracción están las que presentan la letra o letras finales voladas.
>
> En general, las abreviaturas se escriben con mayúscula o minúscula según corresponda a la palabra o expresión abreviadas.
>
> Cuando la abreviatura corresponde a una expresión compleja, se separan mediante un espacio las letras que representan cada una de las palabras que la integran.
>
> Se escribe siempre punto detrás de las abreviaturas, salvo en el caso de aquellas en las que el punto se sustituye por una barra.

Esto indica que la forma "VoBo." no es correcta.

Comment: Es divertido que esta pregunta salga la primera en Google, seguida de la del RAE que enlazas :)

Answer (score 3):

Yo diría que sí (siempre y cuando sea VºBº)

http://www.dropby.com/Genealogia/abreviaturas.html

Visto VoBo en lugar de Vº Bº me resulta un poco raro. Parece el nick de un adolescente poco leido (un *[Hoigan](http://www.gran-angular.net/hoygan-estudio-a-fondo/2007/01/02/)*, vaya)

Answer (score 0):

En la Región Sureste de México, se emplea: Vo.Bo. Aunque utilizarlo como expresa la RAE creo que si generara confusión.

Answer (score 0):

```
        En lo personal, puedo decir que desde hace aproximadamente 40 años, siempre lo miré escrito de la forma Vo. Bo., o quizás Vo.Bo., sin espacio entre ambas, lo cual considero sencillamente correcto, abreviar dos palabras utilizando la primera y última letra con su respectivo punto, ahora veo que lo escriben con el caracter especial ° "Signo de grado", V°B°, lo cual me parece totalmente fuera de lugar, representar una abreviatura o una vocal así considero que no tiene sentido, como sucede en la mayoría de los casos, cambiar sin ninguna razón lo que está bien hecho, pero bueno, solo es mi punto de vista.
```

Comment: ¡Hola! Tu respuesta es similar a otras respuestas anteriores. Si estás de acuerdo con lo que dicen y quieres mostrar tu apoyo, lo mejor es votar esas respuestas y/o dejar un comentario, para evitar tener muchas respuestas iguales. Si lo que quieres es ampliar o mejorar la información o dar otro enfoque, considera [edit]ar tu respuesta para añadir una explicación, decir de qué forma se usa en tu zona, aportar elementos históricos, etc. Más info en [answer].

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/26035)