# ¿Qué significa la abreviatura "VoBo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, abreviaturas, definiciones

¿Cuál es el significado de la abreviatura **"VoBo"**? ¿en qué casos se puede utilizar?

Comment: Relacionado con: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2688/es-correcto-abreviar-visto-bueno-como-vobo

Comment: Se coloca para decir que un documento, elemento o cualquier cosa que se este entregando o recibiendo quede como Visto Bueno...(Vo Bo).....

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Esa abreviatura quiere decir "**visto bueno**".

Por lo general se escribe:

> V.º B.º

Se usa para marcar algo como ya aprobado, o para dejar el espacio para que quien revise un texto, lo firme marcándolo como tal.

Comment: La forma en que se escribe acá es **Vo.Bo.**